# Swift attribute failing to populate during struct init

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have the following code.

For some reason, when I initalize the VerifyPhoneView class it properly prints the verificationID, but self.verificationID remains the empty the string.

What could be causing this?

```
struct VerifyPhoneView: View {

    private var phoneNumber: String
    @State private var verificationID: String = ""

    init(phoneNumber: String, verificationID: String) {
        self.phoneNumber = phoneNumber

        print ("Initializer, verificationID: " + verificationID)

        self.verificationID = verificationID
        print ("Initializer, self.verificationID: " + self.verificationID)
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you tried to remove the empty String in verificationID, just like in phoneNumber?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case no default value for state needed. Here is a solution:

```
struct VerifyPhoneView: View {

    private var phoneNumber: String
    @State private var verificationID: String    // << here !!
    ...
    init(phoneNumber: String, verificationID: String) {
        self.phoneNumber = phoneNumber

        print ("Initializer, verificationID: " + verificationID)

        _verificationID = State(initialValue: verificationID) // << here !!
        print ("Initializer, self.verificationID: " + self.verificationID)
    }
```

Comment: I tried doing this and it gave me '''self' used before all stored properties are initialized' within the initializer

Comment: Worked, thank you! I'll accept once it allows me to in 5 minutes